# Swagger-api with dropwizard.io 0.9.1

Tags: java, rest, swagger, dropwizard

> I try to configure swagger with dropwizard framework 0.9.1.
>
> In my pom.xml :
>
> ```
> <dependency>
>     <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
>     <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
>     <version>1.5.4</version>
>     <scope>compile</scope>
>     <exclusions>
>         <exclusion>
>             <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
>             <artifactId>*</artifactId>
>         </exclusion>
>     </exclusions>
> </dependency>
> ```
>
> but a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   jersey/repackaged/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` is thrown.
>
> What is wrong?

The solution is to set the right exclusions in the dependency section:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You're excluding the wrong artifact. Take a look at [the pom](http://central.maven.org/maven2/io/swagger/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs/1.5.4/swagger-jersey2-jaxrs-1.5.4.pom)

Comment: It.'s true, excluding jersey-container-servlet-core it works. Thx

Comment: This answer needs more love! Thanks!